# How get data in split string data for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Table data is

```
1-"A11111,B22222,C33333,D44444,B22222"
2-"A11111,C33333,D44444,B22222,D44444"
3-"A11111,E55555,C33333,D44444,B22222"
```

If will use

```
select * 
from table 
where data = 'E55555'
```

can get number 3 data

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your requirements by providing detailed sample data and result set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yet another variant

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ','+[data]+',' LIKE '%,E55555,%'
```

The problem though, is that what you are asking for won't be able to use normal indexes, which means an inefficient table scan every time you query. You may want to consider breaking the comma delimited values into their own columns so you can query on them efficiently. As it is you have a 'super' column that crams multiple pieces of data into a single column.

Comment: Hi, Refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2469/7.. The alternative 1 seems to be faster.

Comment: mm, so i will save data format to ,xxxxx,?

Comment: @HaoHan - I don't understand what you're asking in your comment.

Comment: @hatchet: Refer fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/817e4/1.. E5 is not returned. Please modify the fiddle and share the link in comments.

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia - I didn't look at yours close enough. Yes, they should give the same results. However, I don't think sqlfiddle with a few rows is sufficient to conclude which is faster. On something other than a trivial size table, I would guess yours and mine would be similar in speed. In the sqlfiddle you set up, sometimes one is faster, sometimes the other. Any actual difference doesn't rise above the noise. The plan in both cases is the same: table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [data] LIKE '%E55555%'
```

Comment: er...but I want an accurate comparison

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you to handle comma separated data search:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE 
[data] ='E55555' OR         -- IF record contains only this value
[data] LIKE 'E55555,%' OR   -- If record starts with the value followed by comma and others
[data] LIKE '%,E55555' OR   -- If record ends with the value preceeded by comma and others
[data] LIKE '%,E55555,%'    -- If record contains the value in middle
```

Refer [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2469/1)

Comment: if have 'E555' and 'E55555', result it inaccurate

Comment: If you have E555 AND E55555, Only E55555 will be returned, which I guess is what you want.What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: but if E555,E555 and E55555 will be returned?

Comment: i will get E555 return E555, get E55555 return E55555
if 
1-"A11111,C33333,D44444,B22222,D44444" no return

2-"A11111,E55555,C33333,D44444,B22222" get E55555 return, E555 no return

3-"E555,E55555,C33333,D44444,B22222" get E555 or E55555 return

Comment: Whatever starts with E should be returned... Is this your requirement?